# Dynamic formula for referencing sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, sumifs, excel-indirect

I have a formula that creates a summary based on a date range. The formula works fine, but I would like to use a cell say `G1` to generate the name of the worksheet so that each year we can add a new worksheet and by changing `G1` to that worksheet's name the summary is redirected to that worksheet rather than having to go in and edit each formula.

The formula used at the minute is:

```
=SUMIFS('2015'!V:V,'2015'!A:A,">=" &A2,'2015'!A:A,"<=" &A3,'2015'!D:D,A5)
```

I want to replace `2015` with a cell reference where I can type in 2015 or what ever the year is I have named that worksheet.

I have tried using `=INDIRECT` but it just gets lost in the formula somehow.

Comment: Could you update your post to show what the formula was that you tried using the `INDIRECT` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(G1&"!V:V"),INDIRECT(G1&"!A:A"),">=" &A2,INDIRECT(G1&"!A:A"),"<=" &A3,INDIRECT(G1&"!D:D"),A5)
```

where G1 holds the sheet name.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same I have a feeling it may have been an issue with the concatenation in the indirect function.

Comment: APOLOGIES, I now see my error, G1 is hidden there for I was editing G4... sorry and thank you